# Prevent double click on TButton

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe, vcl

We are having an issue in an application with users double-clicking on almost everything including buttons. In some circumstances that leads to something that was not intended by the user since it will fire the OnClick event on the button twice. One idea to prevent this for the entire application was raised and I want to know if there are any pitfalls with using it.

Add a `TApplicationEvents` and implement `OnMessage` to set `Handled` for `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` on `TButton` to `True`.

Something like this:

```
function GetWindowClassName(Handle: HWND): String;
var
  Buffer: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  if GetClassName(Handle, @Buffer, 255) = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := Buffer;
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK then
    Handled := (GetWindowClassName(msg.hwnd) = 'TButton');
end;
```

One obvious drawback is if you have a situation where a user actually wants to click on the same button with some haste. It remains to be investigated if that is the case in this particular application.

Comment: Teach the users only to click once is the real answer

Comment: Hard way: disable applications windows when starting doing some action, and unfreeze" it later. TInterfacedObject with RIAA pattern may help it. More fine-grain option would be temporarily disabling the currently executed action only, if the user is allowed to click *other* buttons in the midst.

Comment: Continuing David's suggestion: learn user not to click, when mouse cursor is the sand clock or looping circle or another kind of "BUSY" cursor.

Comment: @David, disagree; prevent the actions to fail at the second click is the answer (visually implemented e.g. by disabling controls). From my experience you can't expect to have patient and infallible users.

Comment: @TLama Define "second click".

Comment: @David, click, which user performs while a certain action is still in progress. That's what this question is about.

Comment: @TLama If that was the question it would make sense. Perhaps that's really the issue. But the question seems to me to be "how do I stop multiple clicks occuring within the double click time limit?" What's so special about the double click time limit. If the action is not available again until it has finished execution then disable it. Sounds to me like the fundamental problem is bogus use of `Application.ProcessMessages`

Comment: @Mikael How can your button be clicked twice and it cause bad things to happen? Do you get re-entrancy due to you calling `Application.ProcessMessages`? Or perhaps the action runs in a thread but you leave the UI active so that multiple instances of the action can run simulataneously. What I'm fishing for is why clicking twice causes grief. I suspect that your actual problem is much deeper than double clicks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are absolutely correct in your assumption that the application suffers from "bogus use of Application.ProcessMessage". That is when really scary stuff happens and I currently advocate for a work to be done to fix that instead. This question was more of a technical aspect of doing this implementation in `TApplicationEvent.OnMessage`.

Comment: The cases where there are no Application.ProcessMessage involved the users instead experience the effects of actually clicking the button twice, which depending on circumstances can be a bad thing or what they actually want to do. In those cases I too believe that education and explanation on what it means to actually click on a button twice.

Comment: `Application.ProcessMessages` can affect areas of your application other than where it was implemented. That's what's really scary about it. For example, if you call it from within a timer (as if to always ensure a usable application), many things can get distorted because of it.

Comment: @JerryDodge If you call it within a timer then you've no idea how the message queue works! Timer messages are low priority queued messages. If the timer messages are firing, then something is already pumping the queue! Utterly pointless and wasteful to double pump.

Comment: @David, yes, I know, I never said it was a good thing, I was trying to indicate it's a very bad thing :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan any good "guides" on the workings of the message queue?

Comment: @Pieter Petzold's book is where I started

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for your comments on this question. I have cited you on "bogus use of .." a couple of times and managed to steer the dev team into dealing with problem instead of applying a quick fix that *seams* to deal with the issues. I had to deal with arguments like "no I don't know why it is there but I wouldn't add it if it was not necessary". So thanks again and when you see this comment I delete the question.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I'm glad I could be of help. And for once, my somewhat abrasive use of language appears to have been valuable to you! Not always the case  ;-)  I don't think you can delete the question because you have an answer with an upvote.

Comment: @David you are right. But I could at least cast a vtc as too localized :).

Comment: Have one from me too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid that use a constant in your OnClickEvent:

```
 procedure TMyForm.Button1OnClick(sender:TObject);
 const
    {$J+}
    IsInside:Boolean=False;
    {$J-}
 begin
     if IsInSide then Exit;
     IsInside:=True;
     try
         do your code;
     finally
         IsInside:=False;
     end;
 end;
```

If you have a lot of buttons I suggest to use a TActionList for those buttons and capture de OnActionExecute of ActionList event. Not tested, see TActionList for help. I've used it sometime ago.

```
procedure TMyForm.ActionList1Execute(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
const
    {$J+}
    IsInside:Boolean=False;
    {$J-}
begin
    if IsInSide then Exit;
    IsInside:=True;
    try
       ActionList1.ExecuteAction(Action);
    finally
       IsInside:=False;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: How would you get the same effect without using typed constants? Use a global variable?

Comment: Yes, you could use a global variable before or after the Implementation clause. Remember, make sure that the variable's value be false at the begging when the program runs, otherwise, the OnClick's code event would never be executed.

Comment: That's a really dreadful way to implement state. Use a class member instead!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why dreadful?

Comment: @Nevermore Because you have to mess around with compiler switches in code, and because it's actually just a lame way to make a global variable with limited scope. If you have multiple instances of the class then they share the same variable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you so much, you replied after 6 years. I am very appreciated.